# How to remove line guide numbers form pnas-new template(frogs)?

Tags: line-numbering

I can´t remove line guide numbers from my latex overleaf templeate pnas-new

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/pnas-latex-template-for-preparing-invited-submissions-on-overleaf-2023/pdtvjfpyzjtp

Answer (score 0):

In the pnas-new.cls file, you need to comment out the block related to linecount (Lines 251-341), you also want to add a } at Line 250.
Similarly, you also need to comment out linecount related lines in the pnasinvited.sty file (Lines 103-146).